# "I want to" and "I would like to" and "I would love to"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there any difference in the emotional intensity by saying "I want to", "I would like to", and "I would love to"? Moreover, which one would be the most appropriate expression when talking to seniors?

Comment: "I would like to" is more polite than "I want to." I don't think there is any difference in emotional intensity, which is given by the context. "I want to kiss you!" could be more emotional than "I want to kiss you." but that could not be true in all the cases.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks so much! May I know that if there is any difference between "I would like to" and "I would love to"?

Answer (score 6):

> "I want to"

Implies demand. Don't use it with your boss at work, unless you *do* demand or actively strive for something... "I want to win this sales competition" etc

> "I would like to", and "I would love to"

Are gradations of just how much you want to.

> "I would like to go to the business conference"

Fine.

> "I would love to go to the business conference"

Really? You'd enjoy three days of dull speeches & pep talks *that* much? No-one will really believe you.

> "I would love to go to the football match/rock concert"

Far more believable ;)