# Is it reasonable to measure the willingness in money, "would love" vs. "would like"?

Tags: meaning

Consider these examples.

> A: I would **like** to go to watch the baseball game.
>
> B: I would **love** to go to watch the baseball game.

I guess the willingness of the latter is stronger than the former. The question is how much of it? Suppose an individual game ticket ranges from $50 to $800.

"would like" indicates A is a usual fan and he probably would spend $50 to buy a ticket.

"would love" indicates B is a fanatical fan and he probably would spend $800 to buy a ticket.

Is my understanding right? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

---

The examples are adapted from post (["I want to" and "I would like to" and "I would love to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/40171/109190)), my understanding comes from it as well.

Comment: This is a bizarre question. Every language has a similar variety of terms, and in none of them is there a cash value associated (just as big, huge, and enormous don't relate to specific heights in metres.)

Answer (score 2):

No, that isn't reasonable. Someone might say "I would love to go to the game, if you would buy my ticket." They like baseball a lot, even love it, but they are misers and love money more.
The only way you could make a specific differentiation between "love" and "like" is by asking the person who uses the word what they mean by it, and then only in exactly the same situation.

Comment: Or they might say "I would love to go if only I could afford a ticket."

Answer (score -1):

to like to do something is not as strong as to love to do something.

I would love to have tea with you. [stronger]
I would like to have tea with you. [weaker]

Both are idiomatic.